# For what purpose does the Google Play Store use the PHONE permission?

Tags: google-play-store, google, hardware, permissions

I noticed that, by default, the current version of the ***Google Play Store*** has access to the **PHONE** permission.

For what purpose does the ***Google Play Store*** use the **PHONE** permission?

Comment: There is no such thing as a `PHONE` permission. Do you mean the `CALL_PHONE` (make calls) permission – or the permission *group* `PHONE_CALLS`?

Comment: @Izzy In Android Oreo 8.1, it just calls the permission `PHONE`.  Internally, I'm not sure which one it actually is.  How do I tell?

Comment: Ah. According to the [permission overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview) it's the permission group (need to update my list). Then it's most likely `READ_PHONE_STATE` they are after, for all kind of device IDs. To tell for sure, you'd need to analyze the APK to check the permissions listed in the manifest.

Comment: For **ring**/locate your phone from your account settings https://myaccount.google.com/find-your-phone-guide?did=ALbKX%2Bx8OUZhoWZwTtTAgdsO2rqMXPWSKBVs%2FT9CJKAVImKa2O2tNuGVLLGkl%2BwKux3PrudejTFlDw8v%2FHSlZO7ohiO%2BsbO6kw%3D%3D&rapt=AEjHL4OEhuw1NncgzNdzOF6WG-4CJIpI0gqZDqtWnryjCbabG6yUv4VIvTp9LrzPvhbbdL8mmZVBiGcR7WZRwbA7Q8q3tfhVUA&cs=20